# Flutter comparing a value with two strings

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean, intersection

**Here I want to compare the currentvalue with the two strings I gave and I want to create a widget accordingly, but I can only check if it is equal to one string.**

```
Widget buildSecondDropDown() {
    return currentValue == "Kare" && "Dikdörtgen"
        ? Container(
            width: 200,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 12,
              vertical: 4,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )
        : Container();
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try replace line 2 :

```
return currentValue == "Kare" && currentValue == "Dikdörtgen"
```

This should work