# Flutter search on listView with multiple values

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to simply implement a search with multiple values on ListView. It's working fine with a single value I am stuck on how can I use this for multiple values.

My code

```
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 11),
      child: Container(
        width: Width * 0.9,
        child: TextFormField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              searchString = value;
            });
          },
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Material(
                  color: Color(0xffdee8ec), // Button color
                  child: InkWell(
                    splashColor: Colors.red, // Splash color
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.search_outlined,
                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            labelText: "Search",
            labelStyle:
                TextStyle(color: textGreyColor, fontFamily: 'SegoeUI'),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor, width: 1.0),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10),
              borderSide:
                  BorderSide(color: Color(0xffE6E6E6), width: 1.0),
            ),

            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10),
              borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Color(0xffE6E6E6)),
            ),
            //fillColor: Colors.green
          ),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "SegoeUI", color: kPrimaryColor),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      width: Width * 0.9,
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        itemCount: _serviceList.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _serviceList[index]['serviceName']
                  .toString()
                  .contains(searchString)
              ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 7),
                  child: Container(
                    width: Width * 0.9,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 2,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    '${_serviceList[index]['serviceName']} ',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'SegoeUI',
                                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                                        fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '${_serviceList[index]['serviceDuration']}',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'SegoeUI',
                                        color: textGreyColor,
                                        fontSize: 15),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container();
        },
      ),
    )
```

You can see it's now searching with ServiceName only I need to use it for multiple values and have no idea how can I do this or I need to change the way I am doing this

Comment: You want to search depends on list which is data from API? Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807671/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter comparing a value with two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873760/flutter-comparing-a-value-with-two-strings)

Answer (score 1):

You could continue the way you are doing itself. Setup multiple input fields as required and get the value to be searched and include it along with this particular part as conditions:

```
return _serviceList[index]['serviceName']
                  .toString()
                  .contains(searchString)
              ?
```

I guess it would be easier and successful. Do comment if you need future clarifications.

Comment: Nup i need to do from one TextField

Comment: Okay, I don't think that would be a problem. So just use the searchString for multiple fields in _serviceList. Change the data type as needed for the fields if that's the problem. If all are in strings then use just the same condition repeatedly like:
_serviceList[index]['x'].toString() .contains(searchString) || _serviceList[index]['y'].toString() .contains(searchString) ?